# Font Awesome not working in client's environment

Tags: css, fonts, font-awesome, glyphicons

I have a few clients at banks/financial centres where none of the icons generated by Font Awesome are showing in our web GUI. It doesn't seem to be browser-specific (same problem on Firefox & IE). I'm loading the FA files on our own servers (ie. not from maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com). I'm using version 4.3.0.

The servers are physically located in the client's data centres, so I imagine that there are some kind of security issues going on. Maybe an issue with the link to FA being 'protocol-less'? My link in the head tag:

```
<link href="_lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

I've not edited the font paths in the CSS. It works fine on the servers in our own environment, and at various other places.

Most of the fonts (located in /fonts/) have .eot, .svg, .woff, .woff2 & .ttf versions. There are no errors in their browser consoles about missing files or anything. And other resources in _lib/ work fine (I have Highcharts, Bootstrap, etc there too). Saying that I think there is also a similar issue with Glyphicon fonts...

I know that's not much to go on without knowing any more, but just wondering if anything jumps out?

Comment: Are all files accessible and loaded correctly in the browser? When you look at the Network tab in Google Chrome on one of your clients does anything show up red?

Comment: I'll check. I've not got direct access myself, it's through my colleague but I'll ask. Ta.

Comment: That's not a protocol-less URL: that's a URL relative to the current working directory. `//_lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css` would be the protocol-less version.

Comment: Do the servers have mime-type mappings in place for those files? Some servers (certain versions of IIS, for example), don't have those mappings in place by default and you'll need to add them manually.

Comment: ajm is right, this is not a protocol less URL and it could be a server issue with the mime types. However, before jumping from one guess to another I would suggest you first verify if it is a server, an application or client issue, because there can be a great variety of options causing your issue and you don't want to waste time if you can easily narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T8Gy5hrqNKT+hzMclPo118YTQO6cYprQmhrYwIiQ/3axmI1hQomh7Ud2hPOy8SP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: Please explain how that is supposed to answer the question.

Comment: Use the link above because Libraries full and supports the iE9 and etc.